# How to implement NO binary tree in java

Tags: java, tree, structure

I need to read an XML file like this:

```
<body>
<hierarchies>
    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>1</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>1</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code></hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>n</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>2</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>2</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>1</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>n</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>3</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>3</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>1</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>n</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>4</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>4</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>1</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>n</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>5</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>5</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>2</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>y</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>6</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>6</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>3</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>y</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>7</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>7</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>4</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>n</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>6</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>6</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>3</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>y</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>8</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>8</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>7</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>y</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

    <hierarchy>
        <hierarchy-code>9</hierarchy-code>
        <hierarchy-label>9</hierarchy-label>
        <hierarchy-parent_code>7</hierarchy-parent_code>
        <terminal>y</terminal>
    </hierarchy>

</hierarchies>
```

I am able to parse the XML file, but I don´t know what kind of structure should I use to represent it in Java.

A node can have more than one child, but only one parent.

I have thought using a List or an Array of Strings, but I think it is not very efficient.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? You need to chose a data structure that is approritate for the algorithm that works on that data. So we need more information to answer.

Comment: I have another hierarchy tree saved in MongoDB, and when I receive an XML file, I should update my tree in my DB. At the end of the proccess, my tree in DB must be the same than tree in XML file, except when a node specify a parent that does not exist. I also must check another constraints, in order to create a report. I don´t know what data structure is more efficient for that purpose. Thanks!!!!